# how to store the values of request parameter in jsp for next page

Tags: jsp, setattribute, getattribute

i have read in this forum itself when we use
request.setAttribute
and
request.getAttribute

its value is only retained untill the jsp page is loaded.
so they suggestted to use a hidden form and when i am ussing that hidden form - i cannot seem to get it right. it says that it is not permitted for void values of which i make sure that all the values being stored through .setAttribute have some initialized values.

here is the code where error showed

```
     **org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

     An error occurred at line: 83 in the jsp file: /season1.jsp
     The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
     80:   <!-- end .content --></div>
     81:   </form>
     82:   <%i=1;%>
     83:   <input type="hidden" name="epnostorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("epno", epno) %>" />
     84:   <input type="hidden" name="casestorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("case", i) %>" />
     85:   <%
     86:   }


     An error occurred at line: 84 in the jsp file: /season1.jsp
     The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
     81:   </form>
     82:   <%i=1;%>
     83:   <input type="hidden" name="epnostorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("epno", epno) %>" />
     84:   <input type="hidden" name="casestorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("case", i) %>" />
     85:   <%
     86:   }
     87: else if(i==1)


     **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session is one way to store the value

```
session.setAttribute("name",value);
```

Comment: somebody suggested me that if i want to use the values for one page hidder form was better choice .. though i am trying to make a dynamic page here which has to use a value of variable again on the page so can u suggest me how that could be done..

Comment: also if u use session to set attribute will it be forwarded to all the pages where i add session

Comment: untill this error is removed and i cannot test the actual working as i cannot compile the code..

Comment: it will forwarded all pages but if u want remove the session  use  removeAttribute to remove the session value

Comment: ok thanks for the info but if i remove the session attribute on the same page will it be not loaded of .. how do u suggest of the location of using removeAttribute in a website

Comment: also how do i get the attribute i set in session

Comment: session.getAttribute("sessionname");

Comment: Duplicate local variable session - it gives theis error when i declare session variable with Httpsession session; and i have not declared the variable two times ..

Comment: are you declared in your jsp,In jsp session is a inbuilt one so dont use httpsession ,directly specify the session.setAttribute("","");

Answer (score 0):

The method `ServletRequest.setAttribute(String, Object)` is `void` (returns nothing), so there is no value to embed in the `<%= ... %>` tags you are using.  I think you want `getAttribute`, or perhaps the more concise `${varname}` syntax.

Comment: i want to set the value for next jsp page to use .. this is the portion where i want to store the value for the next page to use..

Comment: Indeed the session is one way to get that done.  The important considerations are that you delete it after use and that you scope your names to avoid collisions with other classes and pages using the same trick.  For inspiration:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FlashMap.html

Comment: i dont know , i dont know how it works and i cant find a working example of flash map.. so i will try the session one ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="epnostorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("epno", epno) %>" />
<input type="hidden" name="casestorage" value="<%= request.setAttribute("case", i) %>" />
```

What you have done here is wrong. If you need to set some values in hidden element it doesn't needs to set as request.setAtrribute() inside the element.
You can set as

```
<%
  int someInteger = 0;
  String someString = "stringValue";
%>
<input type="hidden" name="someInteger" value="<%=someInteger%>" />
<input type="hidden" name="someString" value="<%= someString%>" />
```

After that you can get the values from hidden element where the action submit as

```
int someInteger = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("someInteger"));
String someString = request.getParameter("someString");
```